Install and use sagemath in pythonanywhere
I need to use some Sagemath functions in a Flask web hosted in pythonanywhere.com. I would like to know if is it possible to install Sagemath in pythonanywhere? How?
Thank you.
I tried pip install sage in a virtualenv and got:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sage (from versions: 0.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sage

PythonAnywhere dev here: unfortunately not, I believe that's something we'd have to install into the underlying operating system.  We do create new images every year or so, but we're just finishing off the current one -- if you drop us a line via the "Send feedback" link on the site we can add it as a suggested enhancement for the next, but it's likely to be a year or so before that's ready.

Are you trying to install a PyPi package into a virtual environment? If so, there's apparently no package named sage. But there are similar packages including a dummy package for sagemath
